# CLR stored procedure deploy to multiple SQL Server clusters

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqlclr

I have a CLR stored procedure I wrote and in the database connection string in the Visual Studio project it's pointing to "localhost". This works fine when I was developing on my machine.

Now it has to be deployed to multiple SQL Server cluster instances. I deployed it to one as a test and I'm a little confused as to why it works. When you're on the cluster, trying to connect a query window to "localhost" times out and that makes sense since it's a cluster. However, the CLR stored procedure works fine.

I would have thought I would have had to use the cluster instance name in Visual Studio and re-build the .dll

My question is, is the connection string from Visual Studio in a CLR stored procedure even used after you deploy it to a server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would think it is in the general sense. But the question is: does /your/ proc do anything with it? That is, what does it do with the connection once it's created?

Comment: I don't explicitly do anything with it, I use "context connection=true" when I fetch data. That's what I'm wondering, if "context connection=true" just means whatever server the proc is deployed on. Thanks to your comment, I worded the question differently and was able to find the answer. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131053.aspx

Seems that's the case.  "context connection=true" means in the context of the connection the CLR proc was called from and has nothing to do with the connection string in the Visual Studio project.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what the context_connection is for.